# How to wire this NuTone doorbell?

Tags: doorbell

[image]

There’s a 120v outlet right behind the bell.  I feel like it’s missing power and the two wires are connected to only the outdoor switch. I believe the outdoor switch glows but there’s no power/sound at the physical doorbell.

Comment: Check to see if there's a transformer anywhere to feed the bell circuit.

Comment: google *how to wire doorbell* to see a detailed diagram and familiarize yourself. Doorbells typically run on 16VAC, that comes from a  transformer.  So the doorbell is *low voltage AC*.  It is not powered by 120VAC like you would find at any wall outlet.

Comment: https://www.wayfair.com/sca/ideas-and-advice/renovation/how-to-doorbell-wiring-for-beginners-T5561

Comment: and you would use *bell wire* 18 or 20 gauge from the transformer to the doorbell buttons and wall chime ... https://www.homedepot.com/b/Electrical-Wire-Low-Voltage-Wires-Doorbell-Wires/N-5yc1vZc7dc